# CSS Selector Strategy: (Prefix using a parent class: .widget .widget-item {}) or (Directly: .widget-item {})

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here's a very common situation.  Let's say we have some markup:

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-item"></div>
</div>
```

We could style the `.widget-item` with 2 options:

**Option 1:  Prefix using a parent class**

```
.widget .widget-item { /* styles */ }
```

**Option 2:  Directly access the class**

```
.widget-item { /* styles */ }
```

---

Are there any significant performance benefits/hits to the prefix?

If I won't need to reuse the class in another container, say `.other .widget-item`, is there any real benefit to the prefix? (Most of the time, I won't even need to reuse the class outside of the parent, so there's functionally no difference?)

I find myself using these deep selectors, when maybe I shouldn't?

This guy says you should deeply nest:  http://coryschires.com/why-you-should-deeply-nest-your-css-selectors/

This guy says you should keep them simple, unnested:  https://github.com/csswizardry/CSS-Guidelines#selectors

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: CSS goes from right to left. I think the second solution is faster (because it doesn't have to check for the parents)

Comment: In reality neither would be faster enough to make the slightest bit of difference

Comment: Note:  this question isn't just about performance... Don't close my question!  The two answers I got are awesome, I'm still reading through the linked articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [post on Decoupling HTML from CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/20/decoupling-html-from-css/). I avoid deep-chaining as often as I can, because it makes your styles really brittle. From a maintenance aspect, simple `.widget` class selectors are easier to fix and change down the road.

Performance-wise, I think @ [Toni Michel Caubet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219280/css-selector-strategy-prefix-using-a-parent-class-widget-widget-item-or#comment24945068_17219280) is right. Shorter selector chains are less work for the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The decision to create nested selectors vs simple selectors really should be based on how likely you are to need to override specific rules.

**Specificity** and order of appearance drive how styles cascade on one another. While there are performance implications, I wouldn't be overly concerned with most common scenarios.

When you use a selector like `.widget .widget-item` it will have a higher specificity than one such as `.widget-item`. So if there is a scenario where you are using the `.widget-item` in some places where you might want to override some defaults styles then you might add something like `.widget .widget-item` which would be used instead. Similarly you might do something a with a bit less specificity like `div.widget-item` which would override potential rules that matched orginially on `.widget-item`.

Basically, this is how you really should handle rule conflicts without resorting to the common mistake of putting a `!important` all over the place which leads to conflicting important rules that you can't control anymore because they either have the same specificity or not enough for the rule you want to match.

Here is an article to dive into on the subject.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/